# There are no runtimes matching the name dnx-clr-win-x86 on feed https://www.nug et.org/api/v2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I create the default demo web project with ASP.NET Core 1.0, it uses the dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-preview2-003121 runtime in the global.json.

Visual Studio 2015 will ask me to download this runtime because I don't have it installed, but then in the DNVM output window I get the following error:

```
    There are no runtimes matching the name dnx-clr-win-x86 on feed https://www.nug
et.org/api/v2.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\dnvm.ps1:619 char:9
+         throw "There are no runtimes matching the name $RuntimeId on  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (There are no ru...get.org/api 
   /v2.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : There are no runtimes matching the name dnx-clr- 
   win-x86 on feed https://www.nuget.org/api/v2.

There are no runtimes matching the name dnx-clr-win-x86 on feed https://www.myg
et.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\dnvm.ps1:619 char:9
+         throw "There are no runtimes matching the name $RuntimeId on  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (There are no ru...etvnext/api 
   /v2.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : There are no runtimes matching the name dnx-clr- 
   win-x86 on feed https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2.
```

My guess is that the feed URL should point to the v3 feed, but I can't see how to change the URL that is used for this purpose.

Comment: Do you have the latest runtime (dotnet, not dnx) installed and uninstalled all previous versions of the runtime and toolings?

Comment: I installed the latest asp.net core download, not sure how to install the old dnx

Comment: You shouldn't need the dnx anymore, its not developed further in favor of the dotnet cli tooling. The reason I asked is: when you create a new project from the template it should already target the RTM version (with VS2015 Update 3 + .NET Core RTM + preview2 tooling), so I suspect you have/had outdated tools installed

Comment: The new project is targeting the new version, I have all the tooling you named installed, it may be some conflict then with the old dnx then, how do I un-install the old dnx?

Comment: Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features

Comment: Having same issue, any solutions?